# azuresearch search.ismatch is ignoring "1" at the end

Tags: .net, azure, azure-cognitive-search

I have following records -

{

```
"RoleDetails": "0AC05D80-B1E2-4E13-B1E7-602F6C272117 Â pqr Â 1",

 "GroupDetails": "0AC05D80-B1E2-4E13-B1E7-602F6C272117 Â Abc Xyz Â 1",
```

},

{

```
 "RoleDetails": "0AC05D80-B1E2-4E13-B1E7-602F6C272117 Â pqr Â 1",

 "GroupDetails": "0AC05D80-B1E2-4E13-B1E7-602F6C272117 Â Abc Xyz 1 Â 1",
```

},

{

```
"RoleDetails": "0AC05D80-B1E2-4E13-B1E7-602F6C272117 Â pqr Â 1",

"GroupDetails": "0AC05D80-B1E2-4E13-B1E7-602F6C272117 Â Abc Xyz 2 Â 1",
```

},

{

```
"RoleDetails": "0AC05D80-B1E2-4E13-B1E7-602F6C272117 Â pqr Â 1",

"GroupDetails": "0AC05D80-B1E2-4E13-B1E7-602F6C272117 Â Abc Xyz 1 New Â 1",
```

}

1)

When I am using following filter -

> &$filter=search.ismatch('**Abc Xyz 1**','GroupDetails','simple', 'all')

Returned = all records

Expecting = just two rows ("**Abc Xyz 1**" and "**Abc Xyz 1 new**")

2)

When I am using following filter -

> &$filter=search.ismatch('**Abc Xyz 2**','GroupDetails','simple', 'all')

Returned = returning matched record i.e. one row ("**Abc Xyz 2**") which is expected

3)

But when using this filter -

> &$filter=search.ismatch('**Abc Xyz 1 new**','GroupDetails','simple',
>   'all')

Returned = returning matched record i.e. one row ("**Abc Xyz 1 new**")  which is expected

So why it is returning all records when searched "**Abc Xyz 1**" ?

Also note: I tried "simple" and "full" querytype

**SOLUTION**
As per answer provided by Matthew Gotteiner, I modified the query like this -

> &$filter=search.ismatch('**"Abc Xyz 1"**','GroupDetails','simple',
>   'all')

and it worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are looking for exact phrases you should use the [phrase search operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/simple-query-syntax-in-azure-search#phrase-search-operator--) by surrounding your query in double quotes. For example, instead of searching for `Abc Xyz 1`, you can search for  `"Abc Xyz 1"`.

Also, you only need to use the `search.ismatch` function if you are planning to combine the search with a filter using `and`. Otherwise, you can use the `search` parameter in the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/search-documents) or the `searchText` parameter in the [.NET SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.search.documentsoperationsextensions.search?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Search_DocumentsOperationsExtensions_Search_Microsoft_Azure_Search_IDocumentsOperations_System_String_Microsoft_Azure_Search_Models_SearchParameters_Microsoft_Azure_Search_Models_SearchRequestOptions_)

Comment: I am using search.ismatch in Filter and can't use it in search. 

Secondly, search.ismatch doesn't allows "double quotes" that's the reason I used 'single quotes' I am getting exception -
Invalid expression: Syntax error: character '\"' is not valid at position 15 in 'search.ismatch'.

Third, Why is it working fine with 'Abc Xyz 2' and not 'Abc Xyz 1'

Comment: @AnilPurswani It would help us if you could edit your question to include more details about how you're calling Azure Search. For example, are you using the REST API or .NET SDK? Also, why are you using search.ismatch? Do you intend to combine it with other filter clauses via 'and'?

Comment: @AnilPurswani As for why 'Abc Xyz 2' works, this is because there is only one document that contains the term "2", while all of them contain the term "1". Your search terms are being tokenized because they are not in double quotes. You might find this article useful: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-lucene-query-architecture

Comment: @Mathew Gotteiner, Thanks it worked. I had updated the my answer with the solution provided